# How do I create a custom help for my own Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, wizard

I'm developing a new Eclipse plugin which needs to use a custom help in the Java project wizard as I show below.

---

Java Project Wizard Page 1

[image: Java Project Wizard Page 1]

And ...

Java Project Wizard Page 2

[image: Java Project Wizard Page 2]

These two pages use the same as help? if not.

How do I create a help for each page or Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is not really possible to change the help for an existing wizard.

Comment: My wizard extends from the Java project wizard page class and overrides some methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are deriving your wizard pages from `NewJavaProjectWizardPageOne` and `NewJavaProjectWizardPageTwo` you can set a new help context id by overriding the `setControl` method:

```
@Override
protected void setControl(Control newControl) {
  super.setControl(newControl);

  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(newControl, "your help context id");
}
```

where 'your help context id' is a help context id declared in a contexts xml file using the [org.eclipse.help.contexts](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_help_contexts.html) extension point in the usual way.